# How are overridden properties handled in init blocks?

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to understand why the following code throws:

```
open class Base(open val input: String) {
  lateinit var derived: String

  init {
    derived = input.toUpperCase() // throws!
  }
}

class Sub(override val input: String) : Base(input)
```

When invoking this code like this:

```
println(Sub("test").derived)
```

it throws an exception, because at the time `toUpperCase` is called, `input` resolves to `null`. I find this counter intuitive: I pass a non-null value to the primary constructor, yet in the init block of the super class it resolves to null?

I think I have a vague idea of what might be going on: since `input` serves both as a constructor argument as well as a property, the assignment internally calls `this.input`, but `this` isn't fully initialized yet. It's really odd: in the IntelliJ debugger, `input` resolves normally (to the value "test"), but as soon as I invoke the expression evaluation window and inspect `input` manually, it's suddenly null.

Assuming this is expected behavior, what do you recommend to do instead, i.e. when one needs to initialize fields derived from properties of the same class?

**UPDATE:**
I've posted two even more concise code snippets that illustrate where the confusion stems from:

https://gist.github.com/mttkay/9fbb0ddf72f471465afc
https://gist.github.com/mttkay/5dc9bde1006b70e1e8ba

Comment: Error does not occur if `override val` was removed within the subclass. I'm guessing this is a bug, since even supplying an optional value to the base class (and/or subclass) still results in a null error

Comment: It's not evident from the sample code, but I actually need to override the property. The property type passed in the constructor in my real code is covariant in this position, so it must redefine (and hence override) the base class property.

Comment: This is getting weirder with the minute. Have a look at this even more concise test case, in which I made the problem with the property covariance more evident: https://gist.github.com/mttkay/9fbb0ddf72f471465afc

Here I pass 42 in the constructor, and it prints 0. ^^

Comment: Why not declare Base as Base<T: BaseValue>(val value: T) and do Sub(value: SubValue) : Base<SubValue>(value), rather than overriding the property?

Comment: @VinceEmigh Sure, I could do that. It would mean I'd have to go back and change my entire code base to now use a generic type where in Java, a non-generic type and a covariant getter sufficed. Another solution I found I posted in the comment to @yole's answer. Apparently one can change the program semantics ever so subtly by turning the property in the primary ctor into just a ctor argument, and moving the actual val declaration into the class body. That will make `input` in the init block reference the argument directly instead of the property.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The original example is equivalent to the following Java program:

```
class Base {
    private String input;
    private String derived;

    Base(String input) {
        this.input = input;
        this.derived = getInput().toUpperCase();  // Initializes derived by calling an overridden method
    }

    public String getInput() {
        return input;
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    private String input;

    public Derived(String input) {
        super(input);    // Calls the superclass constructor, which tries to initialize derived
        this.input = input;  // Initializes the subclass field
    }

    @Override
    public String getInput() {
        return input;   // Returns the value of the subclass field
    }
}
```

The getInput() method is overridden in the Sub class, so the code calls Sub.getInput(). At this time, the constructor of the Sub class has not executed, so the backing field holding the value of Sub.input is still null. This is not a bug in Kotlin; you can easily run into the same problem in pure Java code.

The fix is to not override the property. (I've seen your comment, but this doesn't really explain why you think you need to override it.)

Comment: I agree this is what happens, but when creating a `Base("test")`, it doesn't throw (even when explicitly dereferencing `this.input` in the `init` block of the `Base` class) ; although the primary constructor is called _after_ the `init` block in this case too. This seems contradictory to me, but _if this is the intended behavior_ could you explain the discrepancy between base and sub class creation process (which I reckon becomes a reformulation of the original question) ?

Comment: Why are you saying that the primary constructor is called after the init block? On the Java bytecode level, code in all init blocks is appended to the primary constructor, and is executed after the code that copies the constructor parameter to the backing field.

Comment: Right, now that you put it this way, it's pretty evident what's happening. Don't you think though that it's highly confusing that I'm referring to `input` in the super class constructor, which is available as an argument to me, and I'm passing a proper value, yet it's not initialized yet? I'd be surprised if I'd be the only person thinking that this is completely backwards.

Comment: @yole thanks for detailing ; my assumption was based on debug logging in a secondary constructor because I have no access to a platform allowing me to check the generated bytecode atm. It remains imo that the discrepancy between creating an instance of the base and derived class is highly bewildering as Matthias commented ; could you add the rationale behind it to your answer if it indeed is intentional by design?

Comment: @yole Here is further evidence why the current behavior is completely puzzling: https://gist.github.com/mttkay/5dc9bde1006b70e1e8ba Compared to the previous snippet, the only thing I changed is moving the super class property declaration out of the primary constructor and into the class body. Shouldn't these two programs be semantically equivalent? Yet they produce different results.

Comment: @Matthias in the last example you are printing the value of the constructor parameter, not the property. Try using `this.input` to use property and get back an NPE :)

Comment: @IlyaRyzhenkov yeah sure, I did realize that. I'm merely questioning that this is what should be happening for the sake of not violating the principle of least surprise.

Comment: PS: I added a comment to the gist acknowledging that it was exaggerating the problem by naming the property and the constructor argument the same. However, this is a common enough idiom in the Java world to still make this a concern.

Comment: @desseim: I've edited my answer to include a complete translation of Kotlin into equivalent Java code, so I hope the difference in behavior is no longer bewildering

Comment: @Matthias: Our design for primary constructors effectively forces us to use the same name to refer to two different things (the constructor parameter and the property), and it's true that this can sometimes lead to surprising behavior. However, we don't have an alternative design which would fix the surprises while still allowing to keep the primary constructor syntax.

Comment: @yole thanks for clarifying, I see where you're coming from.

Answer (score 3):

The confusion comes from the fact that you created two storages for the `input` value (fields in JVM). One is in base class, one in derived. When you are reading `input` value in base class, it calls virtual `getInput` method under the hood. `getInput` is overridden in derived class to return its own stored value, which is not initialised before base constructor is called. This is typical "virtual call in constructor" problem.

If you change derived class to actually use property of super type, everything is fine again.

```
class Sub(input: String) : Base(input) {
    override val input : String
        get() = super.input
}
```

Comment: That is indeed the confusing part, thanks.
Related tracker issue for whoever is interested: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-91 .